# Accessing implementing class in a static context

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static

is it possible to determine the class of an implementing class in a static context. Given i want to create a logger in the superclass which logs its messages under the class name of the implementing classes.

Currently i'm trying to use this approach:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T, ID extends Serializable>
{
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass());

    ...
}
```

But i still get the superclass. Is there any way to do this or should i give up and include the class in the actual logging method when i have access to "this".

Comment: Not an answer, but an alternative: keep your loggers private (which would indeed require you to declare them anew for each implementing class).

Comment: Even if you could the static variable belongs to _GenericDao_. Subtypes won't get their own copy.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables and methods always belong to the declaring class, `GenericDao` in this case. If you create a new subclass `SpecificDao` then it is not accessing a new copy of logger if it accesses it, it is accessing the exact same logger as is in `GenericDao`.

You will need to create the Logger as a non-static member and have one per object (potentially very inefficient) , or declare the logger in each class.

What should work to give you what you want though is if you have an abstract method `getLogger()` in `GenericDao` and no `Logger` at all..

Whenever it wants to log `GenericDao` calls `getLogger().log`

The implementing classes then define their own private static Logger logger. They override the getLogger() abstract method and return the static one from that.